# Update or replace an embedded document in MongoDB collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, document, insert-update

I have following data structure:

```
db.objects
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "object name",
    "type" : "rectangle",
    "area" : {
        "position_x1" : 0,
        "position_y1" : 0,
        "position_x2" : 0,
        "position_y2" : 0
    },
    "dimension" : {
        "width" : 0,
        "height" : 0
    }
}
```

I want to replace/update `"area"` and `"dimension"` separately for a document in objects collection with `"_id"` = 1.

[?] Please let me know how can i achieve using MongoDB C# driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very simple use of the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator. So essentially the update form is:

```js
db.objects.update(
    { "_id": 1 },
    {
        "$set": {
            "area": { /* all of your object properties */ },
            "dimension": { /* all of your object properties */ }
        }
    }
)
```

Alternately you do them separately:

```js
db.objects.update(
    { "_id": 1 },
    {
        "$set": {
            "area.position_x1": 1,
            "area.position_y1": 1,
            "dimension.width": 1 
        }
    }
)
```

According to you actual needs.

Or as C# type code with a Builder:

```js
var query = Query.EQ("_id",1);

var update = Update.Set("area.position_x1", 1)
    .Set("area.position_y1", 1)
    .Set("dimension.width", 1);

MongoCollection<Class>.update(query, update);
```

Comment: Neil can you please tell how to achieve this using MongoDB C# driver ?

Comment: @theGeekster There should not be much difference in the implementation, you are just creating BSON documents to match the JSON form. Unfortunately it has hit 2 a.m here for me on a public holiday so this will be my sign-off for the night. Give it a try, it isn't really that hard, and it's a learning experience.

Comment: @theGeekster So when I have found a moment to come back to this, an example exists

Comment: Thanks Neil for your response. Though I also found it myself with: var update = Update.AddToSet("area.x1", X1).AddToSet("area.X2", X2).AddToSet("dimension.width", width).AddToSet("dimension.height", height);